# GraphQL HotChocolate no compatible constructor find for input type

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate, .net-6.0

This is the exception being raised:

[image]

I goes it has something to do with not being able to resolve my base class.

```
public class Project : BaseEntity<ProjectId>
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }

        private List<Asset> _assets = new();
        public IReadOnlyList<Asset> Assets => _assets;

        public Project(ProjectId id, string name, string description)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Description = description;

            Validate();
        }
...
}
```

Here is my Base:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<TId>
    {
        public TId Id { get; set; }

        public ValidationResult ValidationResult { get; set; }

        public bool IsValid => ValidationResult?.IsValid ?? Validate();

        protected abstract bool Validate();

        protected bool RunValidation<TValidator, TEntity>(TEntity entity, TValidator validator)
          where TValidator : AbstractValidator<TEntity>
          where TEntity : BaseEntity<TId>
        {
            ValidationResult = validator.Validate(entity);
            return IsValid;
        }
```

And this is how I registered the services.

```
builder.Services
            .AddGraphQLServer()
            .AddQueryType<ProjectQueries>()
            .AddType<ProjectType>();
```

And the object type

```
public class ProjectType : ObjectType<Project>, IViewModel
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Project> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor
                .Field(p => p.Id)
                .Description("Unique ID for the project.");

            descriptor
                .Field(p => p.Name)
                .Description("Represents the name for the project.");

        }
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: When this exception is raised?

Comment: During startup.

Comment: Post the full exception text (ie the result of Exception.ToString()), not an image of the exception box

Answer (score 0):

If a type is used as an input object you need to make sure that either properties are settable or that you have a constructor that allows the deserializer to set the properties.

In your specific case you have a computed property:

`public bool IsValid => ValidationResult?.IsValid ?? Validate();`

You can either ignore that property with an attribute or you can provide a fluent type definition that ignores that property for inputs.

Attribute:

```cs
[GraphQLIgnore]
public bool IsValid => ValidationResult?.IsValid ?? Validate();
```

Fluent:

```cs
public class ProjectInputType : InputObjectType<Project>
{
    protected override void Configure(IInputObjectTypeDescriptor<Project> descriptor)
    {
        // make sure to ignore all unusable props here that are public.
        descriptor.Ignore(t => t.IsValid);
        descriptor.Ignore(t => Assets);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, both with attribute and inside configure, still the same error message I posted above.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the class containing those properties being an abstract class?

Comment: should not be an issue.

Comment: I had same issue, InputObjectType did not work for inherited fields for me, throwing an error saying the prop should be public and belong to the type  (version 13.0.0-preview.9), but [GraphQLIgnore] is working fine.

Comment: Same here...this was not an issue in v11; we're trying to upgrade to v12 and this bit us. Also, this is occurring in a non-input type; we want to expose those computed properties as queryable!

Comment: @system.cats.lol Can you raise an issue on GitHub with a repro that the output type is not working? 

Regarding input types we must be able to infer how to set the props of a type. You can always override this and provide your own serialization. Join us on slack.chillicream.com for help on this.